# update the select option using modal in angular 2+.

Tags: angular, angular2-template

**How can I achieve?**

open a modal using a select option, it should give the message do you want to update your value, if user select save from modal then the value should be updated else he has selected cancel then it should not be updated.

***For example :*** 
Below I have written sample code in HTML, right now in the drop-down default value is 1 if the user will select 2 then modal should be open and if the user has selected save button the value should be 2 otherwise it should be 1.

```
<form>
  <select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  <select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just listen to the `change` event on the `select` list:

```
<form>
  <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option value="null" disabled>Select an Option</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

And do the needful in the Component Class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  modelValue: any;

  onChange(value) {
    this.modelValue = confirm(`Are you sure you want to update the model value with ${value}?`) ? value : this.modelValue;
    console.log('Model Value is: ', this.modelValue);
  }
}
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szcabv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.